# Visual Studio C++ strange behaviour

Tags: loops, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

VS2012 evaluates 4 < 4 to true in the case below.
[Here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=438871F286339D3E%212725) are some screenshots taken while debugging.
Replacing the do-while with a while loop solves the problem, but the question of why still remains.

Here is the responsible code:

```
    int n;

    in >> n;

    bool yuri[30000] = { false };
    for (int i = 0, j, k; i < m; i++)
    {
        in >> j >> k;
        if (j > k)
        {
            swap(j, k);
        }

        do
        {
            yuri[j++] = true;
        } while (j < k);
    }
```

And here is the input file:

```
2
1 2
// after the program reads the following values, the behaviour seen in the pictures hapends
3 4
```

Comment: Is your program multithreaded?

Comment: No. I don't use aditional threads.

Comment: A wild guess: `j >= 30000` at the first iteration of the loop. A `while` loop will not even start, but a `do/while` loop will go into the first iteration and will override some piece of data (whatever comes after the `yuri` array in the stack)..

Comment: No. All values of j are less than 10. I ran the program only with j as 3 and k as 4 and the same thing happened.

Comment: Is this some kind of puzzle? Why are you not just posting the entire code here?

Comment: Sorry. I will edit my post. The code is for solving a problem.

Comment: -1: you did not reduced the code to encompass only the problem to be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Your second loop runs up to `m`, not up to `n`. After processing the last two lines of the file, you continue reading and processing. Those reads fail - but you don't check for I/O errors. So you run one iteration of the loop with `j == 4 && k == 4`, and one more with `j == 5 && k == 4`.

`do ... while`, of course, executes at least one iteration even if the condition eventually turns out to be false.